# Creating instances with dependency injection?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I'm trying to implement DI into my application. Below is a snippet of my routes, each route has its own controllers with a method inside of it to return the view.

```
$router->addRoute('GET', '/', ['App\Controllers\Frontend\Guest\LoginController', 'getView']);
```

Lets say I have multiple controllers, inside I have to pass an instance of the Template class.

```
class LoginController {

    private $template;

    public function __construct(Template $template) {
        $this->template = $template;
    }

    public function getView() {
        $this->template->renderTemplate('index.html');
    }

}
```

I use my Template class to interact with Twig, telling it what to do.

```
class Template {

    private $environment;

    public function __construct(Twig_Environment $environment) {
        $this->environment = $environment;
    }

    public function render($template, array $vars) {
        return $this->environment->render($template, $vars);
    }

}
```

Now, the problem I'm having is where should I create the instances of these controllers? Surely I don't just create an instance for every single one of my controllers, that would get messy, right?

Can anyone give me some advice, I'm brand new to DI.

Comment: Take a look at a Dependency Injection Container. I personally use [Dice](https://r.je/dice.html), which I love. You're on a good path!

Comment: Ideally, you'd load the controllers through your dependency container. You'd essentially pass the DI container to the router (one of the few rare occasions where passing the container is OK)

What kind of router are you using? Are you using a framework? If so, which?

Comment: @Stratadox I'm using FastRoute.

Comment: PS: Your template class seems to have a pretty broad responsibility. It might be a bit too generic to warrant injection in a controller. But that's an entirely different debate, I suppose.

Comment: @Stratadox are you saying I could make method calls directly to Twig, making the template class redundant?

Comment: You could, I suppose. I think what bothers me about the current implementation is that although you've abstracted the templating engine away, the controller is asking for a html file to be rendered. At that point, you might as well just pass twig directly, to have less "clutter" in between. Another option would be to inject the rendering mechanism as a "true" abstraction, allowing the same controller to produce html, xml or json depending on which rendering service it got configured with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a Dependency Injection Container. The one I use, [Dice](https://r.je/dice.html), uses Reflection to build your class graph, and has several features that'll make your life easier (caching instances, sharing instances (useful for database connections), and so on).

Basically, it will look up all the dependencies starting from a class you feed to it, and create them as necessary. In your example, in your `FrontController` (or whatever you're using as an entry point for your application), you would do:

```
<?php

$dice = new \Dice\Dice;

// use your router to pick a controller and then
$controller = $dice->create($controllerChosenByRouter);
```

And that's it, Dice will instance `Twig_Environment` to instance `Template` and with `Template` instance `LoginController` which will then be in `$controller` fully constructed and you'll be able to use it as you intend to.

This of course works like that only with type-hinted dependencies. If you have some other parameters in your class' constructor, you can use a rule to pass it. For example, let's say your `LoginController` also needs a username

```
public function __construct(Template $template, $username);
```

Then, you can use the `constructParams` rule to set what Dice should set as that parameter:

```
<?php
$rule = [
    "constructParams" => ["yixoco"],
];
$dice->addRule("LoginController", $rule);
```

And further, if you need to add a rule to a class you're not directly instantiating, you can set `shared` to `true` as well, and that instance will be used every time it's needed, so it will use the exact parameters you supplied:

```
$rule = [
    "constructParams" => [true], // setting cache to true
    "shared" => true,
];
$dice->addRule("Twig_Environment", $rule);
$dice->create("Twig_Environment");
```

So now, a `Twig_Environment` instance with the `cache` parameter set to `true` will be used whenever Dice needs it.

Take a look at the docs, it has a lot to features  to discover that will make your app more flexible. There are of course loads more, like [Auyrin](https://github.com/rdlowrey/auryn), [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org), [Pimple](https://pimple.symfony.com), and those the frameworks come bundled with. [Here's](https://rawgit.com/TomBZombie/php-dependency-injection-benchmarks/master/test1-5_results.html) a benchmark on speed if you'd like to research a bit more on it. They all have their own ways of doing things so definitely read up on them to pick your favorite and the one that matches your needs best!

Comment: The behaviour you describe here is called "auto wiring". That's the process of automatically loading the dependencies of a class. Do note that such behaviour is not the same as dependency injection in general.

Comment: Right, Dice "autowires" the class and keeps everything in its container... Dependency Injection Container and Dependency Injection are obviously different things.

Comment: A dependency injection container is not necessarily the same thing as auto wiring. Although a Dependency Injection Container may support Auto Wiring as a feature, Auto Wiring is not a requirement for something to be a Dependency Injection Container.

Comment: Yes, I agree, sorry if I was unclear. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Maybe these classes can serve as an example: one can have a container, https://github.com/Stratadox/Di/blob/master/src/Container.php and a separate auto wiring solution, https://github.com/Stratadox/Di/blob/master/src/AutoWiring.php - the one is an extension to the other.

Comment: The above comments have confused me that 'Dice' isn't what I need, could any of you verify that it still is what I need? @ishegg I've looked at dice but it seems it doesn't support a composer package, unless I'm wrong here?

Comment: @yicoxo, if I understood your question correctly, yes, it is what you need. You should definitely give it a try, it's very easy to set up. `composer require level-2/dice`, then instantiate `Dice` and finally use `create()` to instantiate the controller your Router says, and you're done.

Comment: Hopefully this helps you on your project. If it doesn't, do not hesitate to come back here and ask further questions! Good luck!

Comment: One quick thing, you've included the create method in your answer but it doesn't explain how you should pass parameters to the route classes constructor.

Comment: That's the magic of Dice, you don't need to. If you properly type-hinted the dependencies (like you did in your example), you only need to pass `create()` the name of the class. If you do need to set some custom, not-type-hinted parameters, you can pass an array with the values as a second parameter to `create()`. Take a look at [this example](https://r.je/dice.html#example1-2).

Comment: Thanks! I suppose if I want to pass parameters to a child of a child (sorry didn't know how better to explain it) basically parameters to the Twig_Environment constructor how would I do that? Would I have to send the whole Template class as the parameter, but then how do I go further than that? The reason for this is the Twig_Environment class has optional parameters for template cache that I'll need to specify a cache directory.

Comment: I added an example. To add parameters to Twig_Environment, use a rule and besides `constructParams`, set `shared` to `true`, so it will use *that* instance of the class whenever it's needed, with the exact parameters you set in the rule.

Comment: Could you add an example of what you just said? I'm finding it hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: Done. (Note that `constructParams` needs an `array`)

Comment: That's great, thank you so much! This has cleared it all up for me.

Comment: That's great! Doing things "the right way" can get really hard at times so just keep at it, you're definitely in the right direction! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A neat way of dealing with this issue, is considering your controllers to be dependencies themselves.

As such, you can (and should) register your controllers like any other service to your dependency injection container.

The bigger question now, though, is how to get them out of the container again. In general, it is discouraged to inject the container itself into just about anything, for it quickly turns from innocent Dependency Injection Container into its evil bastard brother, the Service Locator.

One exception here, though, is your Router. As a rule of thumb, when you're injecting the container in order to fetch dependencies, something is wrong.

The router, however, does not have dependencies on the controllers, and is therefore "permitted" to use the Dependency Injection Container to produce controllers.

For more information and some examples, see the ["recommended usage" section of the PSR-11 (container) meta document](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-11-container-meta.md#4-recommended-usage-container-psr-and-the-service-locator).